# Android onMeasure change View's parameters twice

Tags: android

I've created a new view (extends ImageView) and override onMeasure method.

Xml code:

```
<by.bsuir.klondike.mainCardsView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cardsmain"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
```

At first I overrode a method like this

```
 @Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   width = parentWidth/2;
   height = 210*width/498;
   this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(width,height));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

According to [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) onMeasure calls twice. On it's first call I receive parentWidth == 480 and parentHeight == 320. But on second call I receive parentWidth == 240 and parentHeight == 101.
It turns out, that the size is changing twice.
I've solve this problem using bool flag and change dimension only on first call.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (flag){
        flag=false;
        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        width = parentWidth/2;
        height = 210*width/498;
    }
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

But I think that it's a wrong way.
How can I do it right?